# Why floating point error message is not printing on stderr?

Tags: c, stderr, sigfpe

I am running c language code using a java application using `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`. If any output and error generated by this c language code, I am able to read those via `process.getInputStream()` and `process.getErrorStream()`. But in some cases (when exit code = 136 or 139) like if the code execution failed due to `floating point error`, I am not getting any error in process's error stream.
So, I tried to run my c language code directly on shell and redirected stderr and stdout to seperate files.
Code.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 1/0;
    return 0;
}
```

Command I am running:

```
# gcc Code.c -o Code.out -std=c99
# ./Code.out 2>err.log 1>out.log
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

As you can see above error is printing on shell only but not redirecting to `err.log`. Also, nothing is there in err.log. My question is why this is not printing in stderr stream? As per my understanding if it is not printing in stderr I will not be able to read it via process.getErrorStream. Whatever the error message generated by code execution, I wanted to show it to end user.

Comment: The output likely isn't from the program itself, but either from the shell or the OS.

Comment: The process running your code does not output this message, so it doesn't go either to a redirected file or any stream in the Java parent. When your code gets an unhandled signal, it just exits with an error status of 128 plus the signal number (SIGFPE=8+128=136 or SIGSEGV=11+128=139). **Your shell prints the message** when it receives this exit status, and the _shell_ did not have its I/O redirected in any way. Java returns the status to your code, which can decide what if anything to print.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 That could be an answer rather than a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dave_thompson_085 comments, the `Floating point exception (core dumped)` message is from the Shell rather than the program.

This is a test program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    fprintf(stdout, "normal output, %d\n", __LINE__);
    fprintf(stderr, "error output, %d\n", __LINE__);
    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(stderr);

    int x = 1/0;

    fprintf(stdout, "normal output, %d\n", __LINE__);
    fprintf(stderr, "error output, %d\n", __LINE__);
    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(stderr);

    return 0;
}
```

```sh
# gcc code.c -o Code -std=c99
# ./Code  2>err.log 1>out.log
normal output, 4
error output, 5
Floating point exception (core dumped)

# cat out.log
normal output, 4

$cat err.log
error output, 5
```

When the float exception occurs, it is captured by the OS and forced to exit.